# Is it possible to connect an external camera module to an iPhone audio jack?

Tags: iphone, audio, hardware

I want to run an app from the iPhone that controls an external camera module (like those found on a mobile phone). Has this been done?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not posible to use any external hardware with the iOS limitations.
Also...a camera module...
Sorry

Comment: Actually you can.. however, it will not be accepted at AppStore since you will have to use private libraries to accomplish this. I can't say I know how to do it but I have seen credit cards magnet readers using the jack conector.

Comment: It is being experimented here: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/ but I would like to know if external camera modules can be fitted.

Comment: As Raphael told, it won't be accepted in AppStore, and also it will be difficut to access the iP* hardware at that level